# Sum of time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time, sum

I need a MySQL query for the following. I have a table of time duration as such below:

```
+----+-----------------+
| Id |  time_duration  |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | 0:12            |
 ---- -----------------
| 2  | 0:18            |
 ---- -----------------
```

Using a MySQL query, I need to be able to calculate these time duration. So from the table above I would get the answer of 0:30.